# How to cite more than 14 papers in overleaf?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf, uplatex

I am writing a dissertation on overleaf. 
I make more than 14 citations in my dissertation. 
I received an error that overleaf cannot compile.
Here is my lataxmkrc:

```
$latex = 'uplatex';
$bibtex = 'upbibtex';
$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
$makeindex = 'mendex -U %O -o %D %S';
$pdf_mode = 3; 
$ENV{TZ} = 'Asia/Tokyo';
$ENV{OPENTYPEFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
$ENV{TTFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
```

I got this error bellow.

```
Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams. Learn how to fix compile timeoutsthis is what I got
```

I will cite more papers in the paper.
How can I cite more than 14 papers in overleaf?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  What error did you exactly get?

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] The number of citations shouldn't be a problem, so there may be something else in your project that is causing a compile error. If you can't seem to locate the source, you can contact support@overleaf.com so that a support personnel can have a look. Note also that some document classes require `platex` and `pbibtex`, rather than `uplatex` and `upbibtex`.

Comment: ```Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams.

Learn how to fix compile timeouts```this is what I got .

Comment: I bet the last sentence is a link on overleaf. You might wanna click on it to learn how to fix those issues.

Comment: dear @hikaru_kondo, this is not the first question you ask, and users already invited you to provide a MWE. You are also receiving support from people at Overleaf. Nonetheless, you keep ignoring the advice. Please try to adhere to [the format of TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Otherwise it will be very likely that your question(s) will be closed as off-topic. This is not an helpdesk of Overleaf, nor a forum.

Comment: In general you'd expect that LaTeX has no problem generating documents with more than 14 citations. I myself have written several documents citing more than 14 references and have successfully compiled documents citing hundreds of references. But there are several different methods to produce citations and bibliographies in LaTeX and all of them may come with different difficulties for your endeavour. We can only help you properly if you can share more details about your document with us. Ideal would be a short example document that reproduces the error you are seeing ...

Comment: ... this is often called an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Currently we have no way to even begin looking at your problem. I should say that the error you report here is not necessarily caused by the bibliography or citations and even if it is, it is unlikely to be caused by the number of citations. It could be that you have some code that inadvertently creates and infinite loop or otherwise slows down LaTeX too much.

Comment: I just saw your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531857/35864, where you load `natbib` (which is incompatible with `biblatex`), so I'll retag your question here. But please still consider adding a proper example document that reproduces the issue.