# How to compile image in platex on overleaf

Tags: overleaf, platex

I use platex at Overleaf.
then, I cannot compile image(.png,.jpg,or.etc...).
my latexmkrc file is

```
$latex = 'platex';
$bibtex = 'pbibtex';
$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
$makeindex = 'mendex -U %O -o %D %S';
$pdf_mode = 3; 
$ENV{TZ} = 'Asia/Tokyo';
$ENV{OPENTYPEFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
$ENV{TTFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
```

and my headder of main.tex is

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,papersize,uplatex,14pt]{jsreport}
% uplatex オプションを指定し、ユニコード対応に。ただだし、uplatex でコンパイルすること。

\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}   % 紙面縦幅を本文領域にする（BOTTOM=-TOP）
\setlength{\topmargin}{4.6truemm}       % 上の余白を30mm（=1inch+4.6mm）に
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}  % 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headsep}     % ヘッダの分だけ本文領域を移動させる
\addtolength{\textheight}{-60truemm}    % 下の余白も30mm（BOTTOM=-TOPだから+TOP+30mm）

\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}     % 紙面横幅を本文領域にする（RIGHT=-LEFT）
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.4truemm}  % 左の余白を25mm(=1inch-0.4mm)に
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.4truemm} % 
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-50truemm}     % 右の余白も25mm（RIGHT=-LEFT）

% 数学の文字
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\1}{\mbox{1}\hspace{-0.25em}\mbox{l}}

% 修論本体と表紙で共通で必要となる設定
% \input{preamble}

% 画像の取り扱いに必要
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% 表でセルを複数列で結合する
\usepackage{multicol}

% URLをきれいに見せる
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

% 引用関係
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{参考文献}

\setcitestyle{aysep={},notesep={},open={\inhibitglue（},close={）\inhibitglue}}

% subfigure 環境で、(a)、(b) などの番号を左上に表示する。宇宙系の分野ではこれが一般的なはず。
\usepackage[nooneline]{subfigure}
\subfiguretopcaptrue
% PDF 内で外部リンクや文書内リンクを生成したい場合に使う（好みによる）
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}
% PDF 内のしおりの文字化けを防ぐ
\usepackage{pxjahyper}

% newcommand を使うことで、繰り返し使う長ったらしい入力を簡単にすることができる
\makeatletter

% 氏名などの情報が入っているファイル。各自で編集。
% \include{AuthorInfo}

%URL
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}
```

then, I have error message

```
LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in images/age70death_accident.png
```

Do you know what kind of error is ?
How to fix the error?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: As already mentioned, your example is not complete, especially important here is `graphicx` and which driver you are giving it.

Comment: ```\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{color}```is I am using

Comment: As you have `uplatex` in your `\documenclass[...]{jsreport}` line, you should use `uplatex` and `upbibtex` in your `latemkrc` file, not `platex` and `pbibtex`. Then try removing `[dvipdfmx]` from your `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Make sure also that your Overleaf project setting is set to "LaTeX"; see https://doratex.hatenablog.jp/entry/20180503/1525338512 (though that blog post uses an example that requires `platex`).